# Create window like messagebox where code will continue to run once you close the window

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to create a window on the main thread so that it behaves like the `messagebox` window. In other words I am looking for something like:

```
var myView = new Views.MyWindow();
myView.Show(); // I want to wait here until myView is closed?

// continue execution once myView is closed
```

I know I could create a semaphore to achieve this and have the other window release the semaphore once it closes but how does the message box window manage to do it on the same thread?

Comment: Use the ShowDialog() method instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of `Show()`

Quoting from MSDN:

> When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

the `ShowDialog()` method returns an `bool?` object. Using it, you will be able to know if the user just closed the window, clicked on the `Accept` button, etc:

```
var result = myView.ShowDialog();
if (result) {
    //do something here...
}
```

Comment: just wondering how do I set the dialogResult from my view? Right now I am settting a different value on the myView.Tag property of the window...

Comment: figured it out: `this.DialogResult = true;` it works great! Havent accepted your answer cause I have to wait 5 more minutes ;)

Comment: @TonoNam I thought you were using `WinForms` (didn't see the `WPF` tag). Yes, that's the way of doing it ;)